# How to iterate function so that output is passed as argument iteratively until condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I made a function known as multiplication to multiply subsequent element in a list with each other.

```
def multiplication(numbers):
  new_list=[]
  for x in range(len(numbers)-1):
    new_list.append(numbers[x+1]*numbers[x])
  return new_list
```

Which does the following.

```
multiplication([1,3,5,7,8])
[3, 15, 35, 56]
multiplication([3,15,35,56])
[45, 525, 1960]
```

I've been trying to make a new function with a while loop to pass the output of the prior function back into itself until a single value is outputted. For example, the list above should become a single value of [24310125000]. I've tried using the below code.

```
def final_multiplication(numbers):
  new_list=[]
  while len(new_list)!=1:
    for x in range(len(numbers)-1):
      new_list.append(numbers[x+1]*numbers[x])
    if len(new_list)==1:
      return new_list
```

However, my attempts have resulted in crashes. Does anyone know any way to use a while loop to do this?

Comment: You are always adding to the `new_list`, so it will never have a length of 1. I would do it recursively.

Comment: Can you explain how the expected output is ```[24310125000]```? I am not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to write what you want to do is:

```
def mult(nums):
    while len(nums) > 1:
        nums = [n1 * n2 for n1, n2 in zip(nums, nums[1:])]
    return nums
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are cuter ways of doing it that don't involve a useless `while` and a walrus:

```
import itertools
import operator


def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    yield from zip(a, b)

numbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]

while len(numbers := list(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, pairwise(numbers)))) != 1:
    pass

print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
[24310125000]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get pairs by doing something like:

```py
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

x = [1,3,5,7,8]

def pairs(lst):
    i = 0
    while True:
        _slice = lst[i:i+2]
        if not len(_slice) == 2:
            break
        yield reduce(mul, _slice)
        i += 1


# Then a while loop to check the length
def reducer(lst):
    while len(lst) > 1:
        lst = list(pairs(lst))
    return lst

reducer(x)
[24310125000]
```